# WordPress Media Library Folders + Custom Linux Server Hosting

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, virtual-machine, wordpress-rest-api

I'm coming to you because I have a big problem with my hosting and the functioning of the **FileBird - WordPress Media Library Folders** plugin.
I created my hosting on a NAS, on a virtual machine with Apache.

This plugin doesn't work and after several tests, it's obviously due to my custom hosting.
On other standard sites with public hosting, I have no problem with this plugin.

I think FileBird - WordPress Media Library Folders (folder creation, storage, sorting) can't access the **REST API** (according to their guide). I need this plugin necessarily, I can't do without it, because I deal with more than 16,000 photos on this site, and I want it to be sorted by folder and by theme, etc.

I tried similar plugins, they have the same problem, they load endlessly and do not work.

**Can you help me? Do you have an idea?**

Thanks a lot,
Julien

Comment: This question it is about _configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It might fit better on superuser, serverfault, or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out !
Thanks to the wonderful FileBird's team !

There is the answer :

Add to your function.php file this line of code :

```
if (defined('NJFB_REST_URL')) {
    add_filter('filebird_json_url', function(){
        return site_url("index.php/wp-json/" . NJFB_REST_URL);
    });
```

Thank me later ! ;)